# ASP.NET & Json - simple hierarchy

Tags: asp.net, json

I have a simple ASP.NET Class with 4 properties.  What I'd like to to is package this class into a JSON string and add a "data" parent  at the top level.  What's the best way to add in the "data" element at the top level?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
[DataContract]
public class Task
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var task = new Task();
     task.Name = "Test Task";
     task.Notes = "Test task created by ASP.NET";
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com/api");

     HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Task>("tasks", task).Result;

     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The Json I am getting back from this code is the following:

```
{
   "name": "Test Task",
   "notes": "Test task created by ASP.NET",
}
```

What I'd like is the following:

```
{
    "data": {
    {
       "name": "Test Task",
       "notes": "Test task created by ASP.NET",
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an anonymous class maybe? something like var object = new {data= task}. That should give you the json you desire I believe

Comment: @AndreiD, this actually worked for me.  Any suggestions on implementing it as part of the class structure?

Comment: I would go against putting it in your class structure. This looks like something put in place to work around a problem while interfacing with another system. I would leave the anonymous type as a wrapper but make sure you only put it in one place, so whenever the system you're interfacing with changes, you only have to change one place

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple dictionary:

```
public class Task
{
    public Task
    {
       Data = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }
   [DataMember(Name = "data")]
   public Dictionary<string,string> Data { get; private set; }

}
```

Populate like:

```
Task t =new Task();
t.Data.Add("name","test task");
t.Data.Add("notes","teet");
```

Yes you could create another class and embed it like this also:

```
public class Data
{
  [DataMember(Name = "name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "notes")]
  public string Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public Task
    {
       Data = new Data();
    }
   [DataMember(Name = "data")]
   public Data Data { get; private set; }

}
```

You could use generics for an abstracted `Data`

```
public class Task<T> where T: class , new()
{
  public Task
  {
     Data = new T();
  }

  [DataMember(Name = "data")]
  public T Data { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work and it was something I was exploring earlier.  The problem I see with this is that it kind of abstracts away my strongly typed class properties.  What if I wanted to declare several other classes as well but have them all implement the same "data" parent?

Comment: would me last answer help you?

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on how I would use the generic class in conjunction with other classes?

Comment: you could use the Task class as something that is always passed around with a custom data class.  I need to know more about what you are doing in order to really help.

Comment: If I try your last method, I get the following error: "Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint"

Comment: your `T` class must have an parameterless constructor now.  the constraint enforces it and allows us to create that type in the `Task` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If your service provider is wcf (i guess it is wcf), change the `BodyStyle` of the method to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` as mentioned below.

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

it will not wrap the result.